# What does /u=s parameter in find mean?

Tags: linux

In this command

```
find / -perm /u=s -user midhun 2>/dev/null
```

what does `/u=s` mean? And what does `2> /dev/null` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `find` command, that has several search options:

- The first `/` is path where the search should start. In this case it's the root folder.
- `-perm /u=s` looks for a specific set of permissions (see [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)). In this case it looks for files which have the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) set for the user.
- `-user midhun` looks for files that belong to the user `midhun`
- `2> /dev/null` will redirect the error output to the `/dev/null` device. Effectivly it discards any error messages

If you don't run this command as `root` you won't have enough access rights to search each and every folder of your system. So there will be a log of error messages regarding missing permissions. On way of handling this is to discard them.

Comment: Well detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the /u=s stands for the SUID-Bit, not the Sticky-Bit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).